# Why laravel still validate email even I change to number?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication, phpmyadmin

I want to use number instead of email to sign in:
So, I change my code to:

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('matric_no') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
   <label for="matric_no" class="col-md-4 control-label">Matric No</label>

   <div class="col-md-6">
   <input id="matric_no" class="form-control" type="number" name="matric_no" value="{{ 
   old('matric_no') }}" required autofocus>
   @if ($errors->has('matric_no'))
       <span class="help-block">
       <strong>{{ $errors->first('matric_no') }}</strong>
       </span>
   @endif
   </div>
</div>
```

But each time I try to login, the error is:

> The email field is required.

Comment: Username Customization

By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController

[link]https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: the default users migration that comes with Laravel has the unique contraint to email, you might want to use a custom migration to make your number as unique.

Comment: Could please show the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code in your LoginController

```
public function username()
{
    return 'matric_no';
}
```